# Class 'Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk' not found in Laravel 4 with Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I'm trying to get beanstalk up and running and I'm getting the exception when trying to run Queue::push():

```
Class 'Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk' not found
```

I've run **composer require pda/pheanstalk**, and even regenerated my auto-load file an extra time.

It's happening in ./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/BeanstalkdConnector.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

In composer.json, replace the pda/pheanstalk requirement line by

```
"pda/pheanstalk": "2.0.*"
```

Run

```
composer update
```

Warning: will also update Laravel.

Source: http://laravel.io/forum/07-17-2014-class-pheanstalk-pheanstalk-not-found

Answer (score 2):

Disregard.  Found the answer at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/746.  Apparently the newest version has been reorganized or something.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using pheanstalk 3 which didn't work for me with Laravel 4. Use this command to switch to an older version:

```
composer require pda/pheanstalk "~2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version such as **2.1.1**, and if you are using a namespace `use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk`, then that might be the issue (it was for me). Version 2.1.1 isn't compatible with using namespaces, hence you would delete the `use ...` line and then, when initiating an instance of class type `Pheanstalk`, you do it as follows:

```
$pheanstalkObject = new Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');
```